# Make the deploy of new released docker image pull quicker?

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I have a image with following dockerfile:

```
FROM ubuntu:14.04
# others here
```

Then I do follows:

```
docker pull user/prj:1.0
```

After somedays, I update my prj to `2.0`.
To save disk, I do as follows:

```
docker rmi user/prj:1.0
docker pull user/prj:1.1
```

But I found the new pull will still cost a lot of time.
What's best praticse to quick this process?

Answer (score 0):

Chances are the two images share some layers. When you delete the old image you remove these layers and they need to be downloaded again.
So doing it the other way round

```
docker pull user/prj:1.1
docker rmi user/prj:1.0
```

Will often be faster.

Answer (score 0):

Docker images are consist of layers. Each layer has a unique name, when you rm the image first and the layer is no longer referenced by other image the layer gets removed. So when you try to get newer image even if it has duplicate layers with older image, you have to do a full download.

You can view image layers by :

```
sudo docker image inspect user/prj:1.0
```

As you using `FROM ubuntu:14.04` in your docker file, the best option would

```
be downloading the base image of `ubuntu:14.04`:
sudo docker pull ubuntu:14.04
```